# How to use the "block link" in Docusaurus

Tags: docusaurus

I wonder how to use these **beautiful rectangles with corner radius** in docusaurus to lead readers to other docs.

[image]

I don't know what it is really called... Looked through the [documentation of Docusaurus](https://docusaurus.io/docs/category/guides), but not found this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They're called the DocCardList component. (See the bottom of [this page](https://docusaurus.io/docs/category/guides) for a link to this [reference page](https://docusaurus.io/docs/sidebar/items#category-link))

There are a few different ways to implement them:

Method #1: Creating a [generated index page](https://docusaurus.io/docs/sidebar/items#generated-index-page) as described by [@D.Kastier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5734097/d-kastier)

Method #2: [Embed it into an existing doc page](https://docusaurus.io/docs/sidebar/items#embedding-generated-index-in-doc-page)
Just include the following in your doc,

```markdown
import DocCardList from '@theme/DocCardList';

<DocCardList />
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose that you have the following folder-structure:

```
+-- docs
    +-- Category1
    |-- _category_.json
    |-- file1.md
    |-- file2.md
    +-- Category2
    |-- _category_.json
    |-- fileA.md
    |-- fileB.md
```

To enable the index page (your image) for a category, you should create and edit the file `_category_.json` inside the respective folder, it should look like this:

```
{
  "label": "Category1 Label",
  "link": {
    "type": "generated-index",
    "description": "Description of the category goes here...",
    }
}
```